# Angular 2 Component with ngModel not updating parent model

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular2-directives

I am trying to create a wrapper component for inputs such as a checkbox but I cannot get the parent (inputValue) variable to change, even though it is set as an ngModel.

This is my component definition:

```
@Component({
selector: 'my-checkbox',
inputs: ['inputValue', 'label'],    
template: `
    <div class="ui checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" name="example" [(ngModel)]="inputValue" (change)="onChange($event)">
      <label>{{label}}</label>
    </div>`
})

export class CheckboxComponent {    

inputValue: boolean;

onChange(event) {
    this.inputValue = event.currentTarget.checked;
    console.log(this.inputValue);
}}
```

And I am using it like this in the parent view:

```
<my-checkbox [inputValue]="valueToUpdate" [label]="'Test Label'"></my-checkbox>
```

The console does log correctly and I can see that the internal (inputValue) is updating but not the external 'valueToUpdate' (the ngModel two-way binding is not updating correctly).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to define an output for your component and use the `EventEmitter` class to fire the corresponding event.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-checkbox',
  inputs: ['inputValue', 'label'],    
  outputs: ['inputValueChange']
  template: `
    <div class="ui checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" name="example" [(ngModel)]="inputValue" (change)="onChange($event)">
      <label>{{label}}</label>
    </div>`
})
export class CheckboxComponent {    

  inputValue: boolean;
  inputValueChange: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  onChange(event) {
    this.inputValue = event.currentTarget.checked;
    console.log(this.inputValue);
    this.inputValueChange.emit(this.inputValue);
  }
}
```

This way you will be able to use two binding for your sub component:

```
<my-checkbox [(inputValue)]="valueToUpdate" [label]="'Test Label'">
</my-checkbox>
```

Comment: Have a look at my answer for some suggested improvements.  Feel free to incorporate them into your answer, if you like them.

Comment: Good answer, thank you! The documentation really still needs work!

Comment: Just to add brevity, the EventEmitter needs to be declared with a type, i.e: `inputValueChange: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();` otherwise Typescript will complain.

Comment: Yes, you're right! Without this, you'll have an error during compilation but this doesn't prevent from executing the code ;-) Thanks for the remark! I updated my answer accordingly...

Answer (score 4):

Follow @Thierry's answer (i.e., use an output property), but I suggest using the built-in `ngModelChange` event, rather than having two event bindings.  I.e., having `[(ngModel)]` and `(change)` results in two event bindings, hence two event handlers run for each click.  The built-in `ngModelChange` event is also a bit nicer/cleaner because `$event` is already mapped to the value of the checkbox, rather than the DOM click event.  So, here are the suggested changes to @Thierry's answer:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="example" 
  [ngModel]="inputValue" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)">


onChange(newValue) {
  this.inputValue = newValue;
  console.log(newValue);
  this.inputValueChange.emit(newValue);
}
```

<kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/XQ1NskStYpL8jmkX50j5?p=preview)</kbd>